# Close askopenfilename if it loses focus

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, cross-platform

I am working on a cross platform [project](https://github.com/MaslowCNC/GroundControl) to control a CNC router written in python 2 with a GUI created using kivy.

Overall I love kivy however the kivy file chooser is slow and doesn't look the way most users would expect it to. I would like to use a file chooser which has a native look for most users so I'm looking at using the tkinter `askopenfilename()` function to give me a UI native file chooser.

This works alright, except that if the user clicks outside of the file chooser to bring the main program to the front, the file chooser is left in the background and the UI is locked up because `askopenfilename()` is blocking.

Is there a way to make `askopenfilename()` close automatically if it loses focus?

Any and all help is appreciated.

Here is the code as it stands:

```
def openFile(self):
    '''

    Open The Pop-up To Load A File

    Creates a new pop-up which can be used to open a file.

    '''

    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
    initialDir = path.dirname(self.data.gcodeFile)
    if initialDir is "": 
        initialDir = path.expanduser('~')
    validExtensions = self.data.config.get('Ground Control Settings', 'validExtensions').replace(",", "")

    root.bind("<FocusOut>", self.app_lost_focus)

    filename = askopenfilename( parent=root, initialdir = initialDir, filetypes = (("Gcode files", validExtensions),("all files","*.*")), title = "Open Gcode File") # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file

    if filename is not "":
        self.data.gcodeFile = filename
        self.data.config.set('Maslow Settings', 'openFile', str(self.data.gcodeFile))
        self.data.config.write()

    #close the parent popup
    self.parentWidget.close()
```

Comment: I don't think what you want can be done w/o going as below as Tcl level.

Comment: `import tkinter.filedialog ; print(tkinter.filedialog.__file__)` this gives you path to file with source code of `askopenfilename` and you see how it is created and you can build own version.

Comment: @furas: that's only true on *nix systems. On OSX and Windows you get a native dialog window that tkinter can't control.

Comment: @BryanOakley after my comment I check source code and try to make window closing on <FocusOut> and it seems it uses native dialog window on Linux too - It looks like GTK window - and I can't control it (but I didn't try too hard).

Comment: Ok, thanks all! It sounds like what I am trying to do is not a good idea. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me realize that, and I will find a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `filedialog.askopenfilename` is called method without creating any GUI itself, it calls underlying `widget.tk.call("tk_getOpenFile", **options)`, which then calls `::tk::dialog::file::`. Which seems to handle the file-dialog-gui, on which `tkinter` doesn't have control over *directly* at least.

Perhaps a good workaround would be to hide the kivy window while the process is ongoing.